# Modificar <title> com angularJS através de um formulário

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
         <!-- define-pageTitle -->
    <div id="shareContent">
        <p class="subtitle-app mt30">Define title page</p>
        <form onsubmit="return false">
            <label>Who can browse this hotel:</label>
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="inputPageTitle" placeholder="Define here the title of the page" class="ng-valid ng-dirty">
        </form>
        <br>
        <input class="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Save" ng-click="saveTitlePage()" hyatt-focus-invalid-field>
        <hr class="silverLinemt30">

    </div>
```

Eu preciso pegar o valor do title desse submit e alterar o do meu DOM (title) através do angularJS.

A idéia é que um usuário altere o valor do titulo quando bem entender através de um formulário onde ele personaliza.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa o ng-model

```
<title>{{title}}</title>

<!-- define-pageTitle -->
    <div id="shareContent">
        <p class="subtitle-app mt30">{{title}}</p>
        <form onsubmit="return false">
            <label>Who can browse this hotel:</label>
            <br>
            <input type="text" ng-model="title" id="inputPageTitle" placeholder="Define here the title of the page" class="ng-valid ng-dirty">
        </form>
        <br>
        <input class="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Save" ng-click="saveTitlePage()" hyatt-focus-invalid-field>
        <hr class="silverLinemt30">

    </div>
```

Comment: o négocio é que o ng-model vai trazer de acordo com o que eu for digitando. Mas seria algo na hora que o cliente clicasse no Save. iria trocar lá encima.

Comment: há ok, vou corrigir para você então. 1 min, por acaso está usando algum controller?

Comment: Adiciona isso em seu controle document.title = $scope.title; Lembrando que precisa passar o valor title no ng-model. abrs

Comment: Obrigado @Vinícius deu super certo :)

Comment: Por nada amigo. Abrs